# Use a wCTE to UPDATE a just-INSERTed value

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, common-table-expression, sql-returning

I have 2 tables - users, documents. Using the RETURN, I am returning user_id(newly generated on insert) and doc_id(newly generated on insert).

I need to update a column in the table, documents based on the return values while inserting.

Say, users table has

```
user_id| user_name| user_address
1      | user1    | 1addressline1
2      | user2    | 2addressline1
```

documents table has

```
doc_id| doc_name| reference_id | user_id
1     | 1doc    |              | 1
2     | 2doc    |              | 2
```

I need to update the reference_id column with the value same as
doc_id(returned while inserting)

The doc_id and user_id is auto generated.

```
With row1 as (
    insert into users(user_name,user_address) 
    values('user3','useraddress3')
   RETURNING user_id
),row2 as (
   insert into documents(doc_name,user_id) 
   SELECT '"+3doc+"',user_id from row1 RETURNING doc_id
) 
UPDATE documents 
  set reference_id=doc_id 
where user_id=user_id 
SELECT user_id,doc_id from row1,row2;
```

Say 3doc is a string variable containing the doc name.

I am not able to update in  the same query.

Regards,
Nikhil

Comment: `SELECT '"+3doc+"'` is invalid SQL. String concatenation is done using `||` in SQL. Plus you have *two* statements after the CTEs. You can only have a single (select) statement as the final statement in a CTE.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name   This entire query goes into my java code and thus the '"+3doc+"'.. For the argument sake, assume I do not insert that value(only user_id in documents table)

Comment: Let me re-frame my question
    With row1 as (
        insert into users(user_name,user_address) 
        values('user3','useraddress3')
       RETURNING user_id
    ),row2 as (
        insert into documents(user_id) 
        SELECT user_id from row1 RETURNING doc_id
    ) 
    UPDATE documents 
        set reference_id=doc_id 
        where user_id=user_id 
        SELECT user_id,doc_id from row1,row2;

Comment: Do *not* use string concatenation to insert possibly user-supplied values into SQL queries. See http://bobby-tables.com/, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: @CraigRinger Thank you for that links. But I am still unable to UPDATE the recently inserted row based on two RETURNED values and updating a column(reference_id) with a same value as it appears on column 1(doc_id)

Comment: What's the intended purpose of this `UPDATE`? As written above your query makes no sense, you have an `UPDATE ... SELECT ...` there which is bogus syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A wCTE cannot update a row that it just inserted. One CTE term does not "see" changes made by another CTE term.

Quoting [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING):

> The sub-statements in WITH are executed concurrently with each other and with the main query. Therefore, when using data-modifying statements in WITH, the order in which the specified updates actually happen is unpredictable. All the statements are executed with the same snapshot (see Chapter 13), so they cannot "see" one another's effects on the target tables

and

> Trying to update the same row twice in a single statement is not supported.

In other words, you can't do what you're trying to do in a single query, at least not in the way you are trying to do it.

If you wish to have `reference_id` set to the same as `doc_id` on row insertion, use a `BEFORE INSERT FOR EACH ROW` trigger that checks if `reference_id` is NULL and if it is, sets `NEW.reference_id := NEW.doc_id`.

Comment: Thank you for that. So how can I save the returned values?

Comment: @nikhil See edit. It's hard to be sure, because it's not really clear why you're trying to do what you seem to be attempting - what the underlying goal is, the real problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: If you could guide me in saving the returned values to 2 variables, it will solve my problem.

Comment: @nikhil PostgreSQL doesn't have "variables". So I can't. If you just want to get them as a tuple from the `WITH` query, a simple `SELECT 'u', user_id FROM row1 UNION ALL 'd', doc_id FROM row2` will suffice. Or `SELECT user_id, doc_id FROM row1 CROSS JOIN row2` if you prefer them in one row. It's still not clear *why* you're trying to use a wCTE for this, rather than just firing off a couple of separate queries. It seems like you're overcomplicating the problem.

Comment: Thank you for that. I think I will split my queries. That will be easier.

Comment: @nikhil Yep, or write a simple PL/PgSQL stored procedure, with which this is pretty easy.